# How to get emoji codes in java?

Tags: java

I want java escape code for all emojis. For e.g if anyone put up  smiley then I want its java code which is "\ud83d\ude05" . Anybody knows how to convert emojis to its java code as I said in above e.g ?

Comment: How to get it from what? And what is your output format?

Comment: You'll need a resource to compare to

Comment: Is there any java library or function that will give me emoji's internal java representation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too hard to write one:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class StringRepr {
    private static String escapeChar(int c) {
        if (c <= 0x7f) {
            return Character.toString((char) c);
        } else {
            return "\\u" + String.format("%04x", c);
        }
    }

    public static String escape(String s) {
        return s.chars().mapToObj(c -> escapeChar(c)).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(escape(""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"\\ud83d\\ude05"   You can try this   ,"\"this element hava a special sense

Comment: I want entire \\ud83d\\ude05 code from its emoji.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).